# How to plot graph in windows form using Zedgraph library?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, zedgraph

```
zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
GraphPane mygraphpane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
PointPairList p1 = new PointPairList(time, distance);
LineItem c1 = mygraphpane.AddCurve("Best Solution", p1, Color.Black);
```

I am using this code, time & distance changed on every mouse click, but it still showing a straight line. Is there any thing missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call `myGraph.AxisChange()` to notify axis change occurred. (I guess you will change the axis in your method):

> Note that the AxisChange() method call must be made any time you add
>   or change the data. This tells ZedGraph to go ahead and recalculate
>   all the axis ranges. (Note: This is all AxisChange() does - you can
>   call it anytime you like, and it will update the axis ranges based on
>   the current set of data points. You can also avoid calling
>   AxisChange() if you do not want the axes rescaled.)